# Do files get overwritten in Codenameone when saving under the same name

Tags: codenameone

Maybe a stupid question In my codenameone app I use filesystem storage for storing data (xml and graphic files). Every year I have to make an update of the data. Are the files with the same name overwritten or given the same name with a number behind them, for example filename(1).

Comment: Yes they are (minimum answer/comment length).